# MVC5 DropdlwonList: Set individual column length

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdown list that populates with two fields.  Old_ItemID  and ItemDescription.   The user needs to see both of these fields in the dropdown.

Problem is that is messy.  Originally it puts both fields next to each other without any spacing.  It looks messy and is hard on the eyes.  As you can see from the code below, I added some spacing. And that is much better.

The problem now is that it's not aligned because each Old_ItemID is a different length and depending on how many characters the Old_ItemID is, it pushed the ItemDescription left or right.  And so it looks unorganized.

Is there a way to justify these columns in a tab setting, or somehow get the alignment correct?

Controller Code

```
List<SelectListItem> SuppliesList = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(s => s.InvType == "G").Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.Supplies_ID.ToString(), Text = x.Old_ItemID + "\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0" + "  |  " + "  " + " Description:  " + x.ItemDescription, Selected = false }).DistinctBy(p => p.Text).OrderBy(p => p.Text).ToList();

ViewBag.SuppliesList = new SelectList(SuppliesList, "Value", "Text");
```

View Code

```
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.Label("Supplies Requested:", new { @class = "form-control" })

    @Html.DropDownList("SuppliesList", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "supplychange()" })

</div>
```

Note:  I did a bit of research before asking this question, which is where I found how to add the spaces. But I can't seem to find a resource to show how to align with proper spacing so that it looks professional and not sloppy.  Should be a common request, I would imagine?

Comment: In general people don't really put IDs into the dropdown text, so maybe it's not that common. Or perhaps they're lucky and have consistent lengths (e.g. airport codes or something). Workaround would be to look down the list and see which ID is longest, and then add padding to each item according to how much shorter it is than the longest one. Or you could employ a JS library which emulates a select and enhances it with other features such as better presentation, e.g. `select2` or something like that - there are a few different ones available.

Comment: Can you use bootstrap width classes?

Comment: @pensum - Thanks for your response.   I did see some things online about bootstrap and ways to achieve what I want.  But those also had more code than you can shake a stick at.  Seems like a LOT of work to make a dropdown box align properly.  I come from the old asp.net forms.  This was so easy back then.  It actually tabbed the multiple fields automatically.  I can't understand why something so little needs to be such a big project of code?